# How to query out hours that has more than 72 hours in derived table?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to query out only the root_cause that is more than 72 hours and when it find 72 hours or more it will add up.. For example

I have root cause A = 78 hours and Root cause B = 100 hours since these two is more than 72 it should add up 178 hours as "MNPT". Anything that is less than 72 add up and make up routine NPT

I am using derived table query out but the outcome still display the hours including those that less than 72

```
Select operation_uid, sum (npt_duration) as mnpt from fact_npt_root_cause where npt_duration>72 group by root_cause_code having sum (npt_duration)>72
```

See this table

```
|ROOT CAUSE CODE | NPT Duration   |
|                |                |
|A               |     23         |
|B               |     78         |
|C               |     45         |
|D               |     100        |
|E               |     90         |
```

When the root cause value is more than 72 hours => then add up those value for example
root cause code B, D, E = 78 + 100 + 90 = 268 as MNPT

When the root cause value is less than 72 hours => then add up the value as 23 + 45 = 68 as routine NPT

Comment: Your question is unclear

Comment: @AlexK i have modified it i hope its clear now

Comment: @PetterFriberg ok i have corrected it to mysql

Comment: @rookie_coder, ok thanks, lets see if you get more luck under this tag.

Comment: Can you give us some short example of a fact_npt_root_cause table?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of what you want to do but querying `operation_uid` and grouping by `root_cause_code` assumes that you always has the same `operation_uid` for a given `root_cause_code`... Don't you rather mean :

```
SELECT operation_uid,
       sum (npt_duration) as mnpt
FROM fact_npt_root_cause
WHERE npt_duration>72
GROUP by operation_uid, root_cause_code
HAVING SUM (npt_duration)>72;
```

Comment: I have tried and it says 

com.jaspersoft.commons.semantic.metaapi.MetaDataException: Cannot execute JDBC Query.
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'sum(npt_duration)>72' at line 1
Query is:
SELECT operation_uid, sum(npt_duration) as mnpt FROM fact_npt_root_cause WHERE npt_duration>72 GROUP by operation_uid, root_cause_code
HAVING SUM sum(npt_duration)>72;

Comment: thank you for the answer i believe the code you gave seems to be correct...but that is only when try it on SQLyog when it goes into the jasper adhoc it does not filter the value only to show that is greater than 72 hours...it also include those which are less than 72 hours this is very interesting